# Can someone provide me a link to download XAMPP or WAMP according to my requirement?

Tags: xampp

Can someone provide me a link to download XAMPP or WAMP which should support the following requirements - PHP 5.4.4, MariaDB 5.5.31 or MySQL 5.5.31 or Postgres 9.1 or MSSQL 2008 or Oracle 10.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this link to search for required version

http://www.oldapps.com/xampp.php

Comment: would it be possible for you to condence your answers into one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not happy with above answer, please try another given below-

## Install WAMP SERVER 2.1 and you will get PHP 5.3.5 and then upgrade manually PHP 5.4 following below steps

1. Download PHP5.4 From http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.4 (Download Thread Safe)
2. Go to PHP Folder Location (i.e E:\wamp\bin\php)
3. Create a new folder with name php5.4.42.
4. Extract the download files and save in E:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.42.
5. Copy the following files from your old PHP directory to your new PHP directory()

File - php.ini, phpForApache.ini, wampserver.conf

6. Open new copied php.ini file.
7. Update the extension_dir path in file.
8. Open new phpForApache.ini file.
9. Update the extension_dir path in file.
10. Reboot your system.
11. Start wamp Server
12. Go to wampserver =>PHP=>Version=>PHP 5.4.42
13. Now running PHP5.4.42
    Note: you might need to Re-enable the PHP extension like CURL, Openssl etc